# First time creating raster plot using matplot lib: Only blank raster plot with y-axis appears?

Tags: python, matplotlib, raster

I'm trying to create a raster plot of neural spike data using a numpy array given to me. The array has 2 columns such that the 1st column represents the neuron ID (which should appear on the y-axis) and the 2nd column represents the time of the spike (time will x-axis). Each row of the 2 columns is an individual spike. So if the 3rd column is (100, 200) that means the 3rd spike to be measured is by neuron no. 100 at time 200.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
import numpy as np


spike_data = np.load('spike_train_082019.npy')

pyplot.imshow(spike_data, cmap='Greys')
pyplot.show()
```

This is what I get:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqrI5.jpg

Completely empty. Do I need to "parse" the axes of the numpy array? Can I just feed the loaded array into the imshow function? Any help appreciated.

1st edit: This is what I want to do, but no plot shows up at all now...

```
import numpy as np

spike_data = np.load('spike_train_082019.npy')

unit_id = spike_data[:,0]
spike_time = spike_data[:,1]

pyplot.scatter(spike_time, unit_id)
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: You have an array with some millions of rows, and two columns. If you plot that as image, it will be 7 million times taller than wide - which is what you see in your figure. You can add `aspect="auto"` to the `imshow` call to get the plot fit into the figure, but I strongly doubt the result is what you're after. Yet, I don't quite understand what you want to show.

Comment: Oh I see. So the millions of “rows” aren’t what I’m really after. Essentially, I want a neuron ID vs time plot on y and x axes, respectively. The x-axis values are given by the values in the first column and the y-axis values are given by the corresponding values in the 2nd columns. It sounds like I have to somehow “parse” out the data because the current imshow function is just spitting out an exact replica of the numpy file. Do you know how I can go about doing this?

Comment: `pyplot.plot(*spike_data.T)`?

Comment: So your suggestion created this massive blue expanse of a plot (lol). I've gone ahead and edited my original post to reflect what I "want" to accomplish even though no plot actually shows up. Anywhere you see i went wrong?

Comment: So, I got the exact same output as your suggestion. (https://imgur.com/EhZVLgM) I'm guessing the blue are all the dots/points? Is there any way I can make this plot look more like a proper raster plot like (https://imgur.com/ahVXuEw) using eventplot?

Comment: HOLY I DID IT! (https://imgur.com/8jQ7kx9) I just had to set the radius to a super small value. Could you explain what the asterisk and ".T" do for the spike_data argument in your suggestion?

Comment: This is just a compact way of writing what you did in your first edit.

Comment: Right, but is there anywhere I can read up on the notation? I tried to find what an asterisk does for pyplot.plot but couldn’t find anything online ..

Comment: The asterix has nothing to do with pyplot. It's for argument unpacking. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you so much. And where can I find what the “.T” does at the end of “spike_data”?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much for you help on my first question here.